# Is there a way to see what type of item Visual Studio is formatting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS 2013 and have some Razor code that has a weird background colour:

[image]

I want to get rid of the gray background to match the black background so it doesn't stand out so much, but have no idea which display item this is when I go to Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors.  There are hundreds of settings in there, and the few that I thought represented the code (like keywords, etc) did not change the background.

Is there a quick way to determine what type of display items these are?  I tried right clicking to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Ok, so I found the setting, it was Resharper error highlighting, so I have it fixed, but I'm still wondering if there's a good (easy) way to find the setting versus 15 minutes of trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

It's the setting in there called "Razor code":

[image: Razor code color setting]

Setting that sets the background color. For example, Lime:

[image: Lime Razor]

You can click "Custom.." and choose a more appropriate color that is closer to your editor background.

Comment: Thanks @Simon, but I don't have the "Razor Code" setting, after "Preprocessor Keyword" it goes to the Resharper items.  I'm more curious if there is a way to find out directly from the IDE versus guessing which one it is...